# XML-RPC method parameter data typing in Python

Tags: python, django

I have built an XML-RPC interface in Python and I need to enforce some stricter typing.  For example, passing string '10' instead of int 10.  I can clean this up with some type casting and a little exception handling, but I am wondering if there is any other way of forcing type integrity such as something XML-RPC specific, a decorator, or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML-RPC methods (at least in `xmlrpclib`) are dispatched to Python functions or method, so you have to enforce type checking in them. There is a lot of recipes on doing this task with decorators: [Type Enforcement (accepts/returns)](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#TypeEnforcement.28accepts.2BAC8-returns.29), [typecheck module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/typecheck).

Note, that `xmlrpclib` lacks proper error handling, so you probably would like to [implement your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571598/xml-rpc-server-with-better-error-reporting/1608496#1608496).

Answer (score 1):

It's always going to be converted to a string anyway, so why do you care what's being passed in? If you use `"%s" % number` or even just `str(number)`, then it doesn't matter whether `number` is a string or an int.

Answer (score 0):

I always just use the re.escape function eg.:

```
number = re.escape(number)
```

This way things always gets converted to strings